# Use Results of CTE to Update Another Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following CTE that does what I want it to do.

```
;WITH numbering AS 
(
    SELECT SrcID, AsOfDate, PID,
           dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY SrcID ORDER BY PID) AS rowno
    FROM   RAW_DATA
)
SELECT SrcID,
       MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 1 THEN PID END) AS PID1,
       MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 2 THEN PID END) AS PID2,
       MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 3 THEN PID END) AS PID3,
       MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 4 THEN PID END) AS PID4
FROM   numbering
GROUP BY SrcID
```

I need to use that, as well as the AsOfDate and PID, but I don’t want to display these in the CTE, as that throws off populating PID1, PID2, PID3, and PID4 . . . all of which is correct now.  I do need the SrcID and AsOfDate to do an update to another table, named ‘RAW_DATA’.  How can I run the CTE to generate the specific data set that I need, and then do an update to the RAW_DATA table, based on joins between SrcID and AsOfDate?

I think it should be something like this:

```
    ;WITH numbering AS 
    (
        SELECT SrcID, AsOfDate, PID,
               dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY SrcID ORDER BY PID) AS rowno
        FROM   RAW_DATA
    )
    SELECT SrcID,
           MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 1 THEN PID END) AS PID1,
           MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 2 THEN PID END) AS PID2,
           MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 3 THEN PID END) AS PID3,
           MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 4 THEN PID END) AS PID4
    FROM   numbering
    GROUP BY SrcID
    
INSERT INTO RAW_DATA(SrcID, AsOfDate, PID, PID1, PID2, PID3, PID4)
Select *
FROM         RAW_DATA INNER JOIN numbering 
             ON RAW_DATA.SrcID = numbering.SrcID 
             AND RAW_DATA.AsofDate = numbering.AsofDate
```

However, that throws this error: Invalid object name 'numbering'.  I am on SQL Server 2008.

### Update

Modifying my original post just a bit here.

Jeffrey, I'm testing your solution:

```
--drop table Count_Unique_PID
;WITH numbering AS 
    (
        SELECT SrcID, AsOfDate, PID,PID1,PID2,PID3,PID4,
               dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY AsOfDate, SrcID ORDER BY PID) AS rowno
        FROM   RAW_DATA
    )

    SELECT SrcID,AsOfDate, PID,
           MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 1 THEN PID END) AS PID1,
           MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 2 THEN PID END) AS PID2,
           MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 3 THEN PID END) AS PID3,
           MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 4 THEN PID END) AS PID4
    INTO Count_Unique_PID
    FROM   numbering
    GROUP BY SrcID,AsOfDate, PID

    SELECT SrcID,
           AsOfDate,
           PID,
           PID1,
           PID2,
           PID3,
           PID4
    FROM   Count_Unique_PID
    GROUP BY SrcID,AsOfDate, PID,PID1,PID2,PID3,PID4


UPDATE    RAW_DATA
SET              PID1 = B.PID1, 
                 PID2 = B.PID2,
                 PID3 = B.PID3,
                 PID4 = B.PID4
FROM         RAW_DATA AS A INNER JOIN Count_Unique_PID  As B
             ON A.SrcID = B.SrcID 
             AND A.AsofDate = B.AsofDate
```

This runs, but it blows up my rows from 357,518 to 724,150.  The number of records should stay the same; it should remain 357,518 after the Update is done...something is still not quite right here.  Maybe I am missing a Group By somewhere, or something like that.  I don't see what the actual problem is.  Any additional thoughts on this?

Comment: From the documentation: "A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a *single* SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement." Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTEs can only be referenced by the immediately-following statement. If you need the results later, you could insert the CTE into a temp table, then select from that temp table and then insert from that temp table:

```
;WITH numbering AS 
    (
        SELECT SrcID, AsOfDate, PID,
               dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY SrcID ORDER BY PID) AS rowno
        FROM   RAW_DATA
    )

    SELECT SrcID,
           MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 1 THEN PID END) AS PID1,
           MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 2 THEN PID END) AS PID2,
           MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 3 THEN PID END) AS PID3,
           MAX(CASE rowno WHEN 4 THEN PID END) AS PID4
    INTO #tmp
    FROM   numbering
    GROUP BY SrcID

    SELECT SrcID,
           PID1,
           PID2,
           PID3,
           PID4
    FROM   #tmp
    GROUP BY SrcID

INSERT INTO RAW_DATA(SrcID, AsOfDate, PID, PID1, PID2, PID3, PID4)
Select *
FROM         RAW_DATA INNER JOIN #tmp
             ON RAW_DATA.SrcID = #tmp.SrcID 
             AND RAW_DATA.AsofDate = #tmp.AsofDate
```

Comment: I simply joined on one more field and got the number of records I was looking for.  Thanks Jeffrey!

Answer (score 0):

You need encapsulate your query as a second cte:

sintaxis is

```
WITH cte1 as (
   SELECT ...
), cte2  as (
   SELECT *
   FROM cte1
   .....
)
INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT * 
FROM cte2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT statement is doing nothing for the insert (maybe it's for validation). Simply remove the select statement and your insert should work.

```
;WITH numbering AS 
(
    SELECT SrcID, AsOfDate, PID,
           dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY SrcID ORDER BY PID) AS rowno
    FROM   RAW_DATA
)


INSERT INTO RAW_DATA(SrcID, AsOfDate, PID, PID1, PID2, PID3, PID4)
Select *
FROM         
         RAW_DATA INNER JOIN numbering 
         ON RAW_DATA.SrcID = numbering.SrcID 
         AND RAW_DATA.AsofDate = numbering.AsofDate
```

If you need to run a select on the CTE as well, you should use a temp table to it will exist as long as the query is running.

Comment: I guess you miss the group by ?

Comment: I saw to the group by but based on how the SQL was written it was not taken into account for the insert, it was there only for the output

Comment: He insert `PID, PID1, PID2, PID3, PID4` those are the result of the `MAX()`

Comment: I see what your saying, but his query was only inserting/joining on the cte not that he could reference the select statement the way it was written